# Why the facebook newMeRequest is not response?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

I used the following code to get my facebook user profile, the problem is , when I trigger the newMeRequest, it never response.

The session is already opened and I have also add the internet permission at manifest.xml, how to fix it ? Thanks for helping

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private View rootView;
private ImageView profilePic;
private Context ctx;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ctx = getActivity();

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
    profilePic = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Log.d("test1","success 123");
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new MeReqCallback());
    } else {
        Log.d("test1","fail 123");
    }

    return rootView;
}

private class MeReqCallback implements GraphUserCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        Log.d("test1",response.getError().getErrorMessage());
        new ImageLoader(ctx).execute(profilePic,"https://graph.facebook.com/"+ user.getId() +"/picture");
    }       
}
```

After logging, it fall into success 123, but it even did not fall into the onCompleted function , that means even no error message logged.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't actually execute the request. Add `.executeAsync()` on the end of your request definition.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same problem to which I answered here ([app crash when try get user photo by Facebook iOS Graph API with app-scoped user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994958/app-crash-when-try-get-user-photo-by-facebook-ios-graph-api-with-app-scoped-user/23995260#23995260)) yesterday.

Requesting `/me/picture` results in a http 304 redirect, and apparently `ImageLoader()` can't handle redirects the way you're using it currently.

Comment: I need to use .executeAsync() 
and also I need to handle the redirect of facebook profile pic URL